Having issue with Chainklink job
I'm trying to set up a job in my Chainlink Node. I deployed Operator and ATestnetConsumer contracts as mentioned in here. When I call the requestEthereumPrice function, the node starts a job run but then it will get suspended in the submit_tx part. I funded the wallet with 0.3 sETH but didn't work. This is the job definition:
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Uint256 - (TOML)"
externalJobID = "07b730e5-6283-4eed-bc86-e1223bc13811"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0x61c4AF079C1aB48A1145D9cAbc0a632080BcEbFc"
evmChainID = "11155111"
minIncomingConfirmations = 0
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = "0"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)" allowUnrestrictedNetworkAccess="true"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]

    multiply     [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times="$(decode_cbor.times)"]

    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256 value)" data="{ \\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"value\\": $(multiply) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\":   $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                  ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x61c4AF079C1aB48A1145D9cAbc0a632080BcEbFc" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""

This is the JSON output of the run:
{
  "__typename": "JobRun",
  "id": "4",
  "allErrors": [
  ],
  "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.484768Z",
  "fatalErrors": [
  ],
  "finishedAt": null,
  "job": {
    "__typename": "Job",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Get > Uint256 - (TOML)",
    "observationSource": " decode_log [type="ethabidecodelog" abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)" data="$(jobRun.logData)" topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"] decode_cbor [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"] fetch [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)" allowUnrestrictedNetworkAccess="true"] parse [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"] multiply [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times="$(decode_cbor.times)"] encode_data [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256 value)" data="{ \"requestId\": $(decode_log.requestId), \"value\": $(multiply) }"] encode_tx [type="ethabiencode" abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)" data="{\"requestId\": $(decode_log.requestId), \"payment\": $(decode_log.payment), \"callbackAddress\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \"callbackFunctionId\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \"expiration\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \"data\": $(encode_data)}" ] submit_tx [type="ethtx" to="0x61c4AF079C1aB48A1145D9cAbc0a632080BcEbFc" data="$(encode_tx)"] decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx "
  },
  "status": "SUSPENDED",
  "inputs": {
    "jobRun": {
      "blockReceiptsRoot": "0x974f0d621b2eb3e377b9944a9d3cc6bfa1fd1992928075190043ce9c7ae44f30",
      "blockStateRoot": "0x1b84dd3d1842bb9d8be19d95f0559f0a19a57e6e83c81ffe68abd1d71bae0de2",
      "blockTransactionsRoot": "0x3b19a2fd6b90bc58156990aaa49b6c53226cd695f9294213d08754d62dd86a8a",
      "logAddress": "0x61c4AF079C1aB48A1145D9cAbc0a632080BcEbFc",
      "logBlockHash": "0xf464277c4beca7f7df798b79b86d83d62ef64b23d783e32e2452ba8ac1982e98",
      "logBlockNumber": 6171430,
      "logData": "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",
      "logTopics": [
        "0xd8d7ecc4800d25fa53ce0372f13a416d98907a7ef3d8d3bdd79cf4fe75529c65",
        "0x3037623733306535363238333465656462633836653132323362633133383131"
      ],
      "logTxHash": "0xabecfef4fcf0daaa4b760efcbc7b770ab2dacceca3d9e840d4fc073fcab9059e",
      "meta": {
        "oracleRequest": {
          "callbackAddr": "0x5411B40B49C47DFe93075B04dD57980fD05c4Eee",
          "callbackFunctionId": "0x92cdaaf3",
          "cancelExpiration": "1719173664",
          "data": "0x63676574783f68747470733a2f2f6d696e2d6170692e63727970746f636f6d706172652e636f6d2f646174612f70726963653f6673796d3d455448267473796d733d5553446470617468635553446574696d65731864",
          "dataVersion": "1",
          "payment": "100000000000000000",
          "requestId": "0x2f355027ec182c8c2036408dfb9367e6d18097101dd489ca7efd4ea7c27f7650",
          "requester": "0x5411B40B49C47DFe93075B04dD57980fD05c4Eee",
          "specId": "0x3037623733306535363238333465656462633836653132323362633133383131"
        }
      }
    },
    "jobSpec": {
      "databaseID": 1,
      "evmChainID": "11155111",
      "externalJobID": "0x07b730e562834eedbc86e1223bc13811",
      "name": "Get > Uint256 - (TOML)",
      "pipelineSpec": {
        "ID": 0,
        "dotDagSource": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "outputs": [
    "error: unable to retrieve outputs"
  ],
  "taskRuns": [
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "dc56c416-2352-4a81-b7a2-14e212a2b0cd",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.486276Z",
      "dotID": "submit_tx",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "output": "null",
      "type": "ethtx"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "2592d35c-6b7e-40da-bcca-19f873644db9",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.492846Z",
      "dotID": "decode_log",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.493017Z",
      "output": "{"callbackAddr":"0x5411B40B49C47DFe93075B04dD57980fD05c4Eee","callbackFunctionId":"0x92cdaaf3","cancelExpiration":1719173664,"data":"0x63676574783f68747470733a2f2f6d696e2d6170692e63727970746f636f6d706172652e636f6d2f646174612f70726963653f6673796d3d455448267473796d733d5553446470617468635553446574696d65731864","dataVersion":1,"payment":100000000000000000,"requestId":"0x2f355027ec182c8c2036408dfb9367e6d18097101dd489ca7efd4ea7c27f7650","requester":"0x5411B40B49C47DFe93075B04dD57980fD05c4Eee","specId":"0x3037623733306535363238333465656462633836653132323362633133383131"}",
      "type": "ethabidecodelog"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "90ba43f0-b09f-4738-9d3b-7cdcf25afaa1",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.49305Z",
      "dotID": "decode_cbor",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.493087Z",
      "output": "{"get":"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH\u0026tsyms=USD","path":"USD","times":100}",
      "type": "cborparse"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "aaf8e62e-920b-49f1-889f-1f2b81b0871c",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:49.4931Z",
      "dotID": "fetch",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111485Z",
      "output": ""{\"USD\":3476.19}"",
      "type": "http"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "c9186825-1dd1-4025-a0ce-566419ad0515",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111554Z",
      "dotID": "parse",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111661Z",
      "output": "3476.19",
      "type": "jsonparse"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "fea73758-91ec-4027-8ebf-0dc63c39c60f",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111837Z",
      "dotID": "multiply",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111868Z",
      "output": ""347619"",
      "type": "multiply"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "59abd9b7-c1be-49b9-99cd-00830a4e1f87",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.111885Z",
      "dotID": "encode_data",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.11204Z",
      "output": ""0x2f355027ec182c8c2036408dfb9367e6d18097101dd489ca7efd4ea7c27f76500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054de3"",
      "type": "ethabiencode"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "259871f1-012d-41ff-9467-a7c6fb0d0054",
      "createdAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.112076Z",
      "dotID": "encode_tx",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2024-06-23T20:09:50.112225Z",
      "output": ""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"",
      "type": "ethabiencode"
    }
  ]
}


It was solved by moving the API from Infura to Alchemy.

glad this worked out - was looking it with a colleague.  Have you explored Chainlink Functions as a faster/easier alternative?
